# Google Trends API - More than 5 Search terms in the CSV File

Tags: api, csv, google-analytics, google-trends

So when I go to the Google Trends Webpage I can download a CSV File. (Actions Menu with the arrow symbol)

So for example like this:

[Google Trends Example](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=%2Fm%2F0mgkg,%2Fm%2F04sv4,%2Fm%2F0k8z,%2Fm%2F0lwkh,%2Fm%2F03sc8)

In this CSV File I can compare only up to 5 companies. But I would like to compare arround 1'000 Search terms with an API. Is there a way to do this?

I checked Google DataAPI's, but I can't figure it out:

[Google Data API's](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to export multiple CSV files, normalize, and compare yourself. [Details here.](https://digitaljobstobedone.com/2017/07/10/how-do-you-compare-large-numbers-of-items-in-google-trends/) [And here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/25fuyp/how_to_download_500_query_searches_in_google/) Not the answer everyone was hoping for, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

5 search terms is the limit.
Have a look at error from /api/explore when you make a request.

`com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: Too many comparison items for explore: 6.`

https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=a,b,c,d,e - OK
https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=a,b,c,d,e,f - Error